# How to use "display: none;" on a span element which is inside a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Im using the social-share-button gem to share blog post on social media. I have internationalized the website meaning the website is bilingual (english and german). Everything works fine but I have an issue on the social share buttons if I switch to german:

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="share_box">
    <% if I18n.locale == :de %>
        <h3 class="share_title wow bounceIn" data-wow-duration="1400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">Teile diesen beitrag</h3>
    <% else %>
        <h3 class="share_title wow bounceIn" data-wow-duration="1400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">Share this Post</h3>
    <% end %>
    <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">
        <% if I18n.locale == :de %>
            <%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title_de, :url => post_url(@post)) %>
        <% else %>
            <%= social_share_button_tag(@post.title_en, :url => post_url(@post)) %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**English:**

[image]

```
<a rel="nofollow " data-site="twitter" class="ssb-icon ssb-twitter" onclick="return SocialShareButton.share(this);" title="Share to Twitter" href="#"></a>
```

**German:**

[image]

```
<a rel="nofollow " data-site="twitter" class="ssb-icon ssb-twitter" onclick="return SocialShareButton.share(this);" title="<span class=" translation_missing"="">Share To" href="#"&gt;</a>
```

As you can see there is a translation missing inside the gem and thats why this ugly text appears! To solve this issue I want to not display the text with css. Unfortunately I have huge issues to trigger the text!

This is so far what I have tried:

**1) Had zero effect**

```
.translation_missing {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**2) The whole icons disappeared**

```
a[title] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**3) Tried to get rid of it with JavaScript (Only the hover text disappeared)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").removeAttr("title");
});
```

Hover text was:

```
<span class=
```

Element on Inspect with JavaScript:

```
<a rel="nofollow " data-site="twitter" class="ssb-icon ssb-twitter" onclick="return SocialShareButton.share(this);" translation_missing"="">Share To" href="#"&gt;</a>
```

**If anyone has any hints how to solve this issues and remove this ugly text I would be very happy! Thanks in advance!**

Comment: isn't the real issue in the missing translation?

Comment: absolutely but I dont might if a translation is missing inside a gem if everything works perfectly :) all I need to is to disappear the text...

Comment: and where does the span come from?

Comment: Are you using any css framework? If yes: it might be over-writing your span css properties. Try this:  
              `#share_box> span {display:none;}`

Comment: This is an issue to be solved on RoR side. Not js or css. Because RoR renders invalid html.

Comment: If you can where is the class with the translation missing use ' instead "

Comment: You could take a look to the [locale](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/config/locales/social_share_button.en.yml) @trickydiddy, I think is easier, and most probably you'll need it more than once.

Comment: <a rel="nofollow " data-site="twitter" class="ssb-icon ssb-twitter" onclick="return SocialShareButton.share(this);" title="<span class='translation_missing'></span>"
href="#">Hie</a>

with 

.translation_missing{
  display:none;
}

Comment: @EugenAz Thanks for your advice I forked and updated the gem and now its working! ;)

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Thanks! ;) I have updated the gem and it seems to work! ;)

Comment: @rebecca I think from the gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of littering your code with conditionals you can use dynamic calling and the I18n module.

```
module PostsHelper
  def localized_title(post, locale: I18n.locale)
    post.public_send("title_#{locale.to_s}")
  end
end
```

---

```
<div id="share_box">
  <h3 class="share_title wow bounceIn" data-wow-duration="1400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms"><%= t('.share_this_post') %></h3>
   <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1400ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">
     <%= social_share_button_tag(localized_title(@post), url: post_url(@post)) %>
   </div>
</div>
```

The code in that gem is not great - in order to not produce invalid HTML [this line](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/d8b7785504749d5ae4e13c25d9454def98ed2821/lib/social_share_button/helper.rb#L18):

```
link_title = t "social_share_button.share_to", :name => t("social_share_button.#{name.downcase}")
```

Should check if the translation exists (with `translate!`) or provide a default:

```
link_title = strip_tags(t("social_share_button.share_to", default: 'Share to')), :name => strip_tags(t("social_share_button.#{name.downcase}", default: name))
```

If you are really attached to that particular gem [fork and fix it and send a pull request](https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962). Otherwise there are plenty of alternatives.

Comment: `strip_tags` is just an extra guarantee against clever people adding markup in the localization files.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! This helped me a lot! I resolved the issue by forking and fixing the gem! This was very useful!